# What is happening with this *param_1?

Tags: x86, c, ghidra, local-variables

I am a bit of a starter, so bear with me as I can't find the answer through Google (a common thing in Ghidra work I noticed so far).

I have a function that seems to read like it is a Constructor.
But I am having trouble what it is doing, mainly because I think I don't understand the C language that well.

The code I am confused about is this:

The code as C:

[image: The code as C]

The code as ASM:

[image: The code as ASM]

Sorry for using screenshots, I couldn't get the ASM to reasonably copy and paste into here.

`*param_1`, is set to a specific address. What this * in front of the variable means, I can't really find besides people saying "You shouldn't do that in C code!"

What it then starts doing is nulling out some variables in an array or struct that `param_1` apparently is now (going by the ASM, `param_1 == ECX` and so probably `_this_`?) the rest seems irrelevant for now.

What is at `0x497e68`? It is an address, that then points towards another bit of code at `0x438170`. And while this `0x497e68` address is references 4 times, all of them do so in a similar manner, and thus I never see a direct "CALL" to this indirect method. The method itself is simply calling _free on ECX. It's not special.

So what is going on here? Is there a reasonable explanation as to why this is happening? And what should I actually be reading here?
And if so, is there then a way I can convince Ghidra to present this in a more sensible way?

Comment: it is like int bar = 5: . int* myintarr [4]={ &bar,null,null,null};

Comment: You are probably looking at code that was originally `C++` rather than `C`. `0x497e68` is the address of the virtual function table or vtable. This is an array of function pointers. `*param_1` is the same as `param_1[0]` and is set of the address of the vtable.